# SQL latest entry

Tags: sql, sql-server

So this is most likely a long shot.

I have a table named 'Case' that has primary key 'Case_ID'.  In another table named 'CaseStatus' there is a column named 'value' which just has items like pending, researching,... etc.

My issue is everytime the status is updated, I am getting duplicate 'Case_ID's

How can I select the latest entry (essentially showing the current 'status')?

There is no date, however both tables share a column named 'Last_Mod_Date'. I am not sure if that helps.  I have done tons of searching on here and most people are looking for something like a MAX DATE but my brain doesn't want to work for some reason and I cannot connect the dots.

I appreciate everyone's help.  I have fixed it.  I'd post it but probably won't make sense without seeing the whole picture... here is the relevant part I think:

```
where
B.[CASE_ID] = A.CASE_ID
and B.LAST_ONE = 'Y'
and C.[TYPE] = 'STATUS'
and [DIS].[TYPE] = 'DISPOSITION'
```

Comment: Without a date this is going to be hard, you can do a Max(Last_Mod_Date)

Comment: More information is needed like version/type of SQL and what code you're using.

Comment: assuming your primary key (Case_ID) is an auto-increment, all you need to do is grab the MAX of the Case_ID.

Comment: SQL 2008 R2 is the version

Comment: My apologies, I can't figure out how to make it readable on here.  As you can see it's not the only part of the Q.

Answer (score 0):

In the CaseStatus table you need to add a status change date. Without that you have no reliable way of getting the latest status.

Another option is to use an UPDATE instead of an INSERT when changing status. That way you will always have one row per case ID.

Comment: Is there anyway to use the "last_mod_date"

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This will give you one row for the case and one for the case status.

```
select *
from [CASE] C
inner join 
    (select cs.CASE_ID, cs.Status
    from CaseStatus cs
    where C.[TYPE] = 'STATUS'
    and cs.CaseStatus_ID in
        (select max(s.CaseStatus_ID) maxID
        from CaseStatus s
        where s.[TYPE] = 'STATUS'
        group by s.CASE_ID)) as cs
on c.Case_ID = cs.Case_ID
```

Normally you would just have a CASE.CaseStatusID column that would hold the latest status and then you would use triggers to capture the history if you ever needed it.  Also, I would stay away from using reserved words like CASE for my object names.